# How do i read, modify and write to the same file without involving a temporary file in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I like keeping my history files uncluttered. Since zsh has excellent history searching features, there is no need to save all the commands that I repeatedly use (e.g., finger, pwd, ls, etc) multiple times. To strip the history file of all duplicate lines, I did `sort .zhistory|uniq -du`. Now, I'd like to write this back to the same file, so that if I simply put this in my `.zshrc`, everytime I login, my history is trimmed and clean. If I try `sort .zhistory|uniq -du>.zhistory`, the resulting file is empty! On the other hand, if I do `sort .zhistory|uniq -du>tempfile`, it writes to `tempfile` correctly. Any idea how I can write to the same file?

Comment: What's wrong with the temporary file? Alas, i do not know of a way to avoid one. It's fairly straightforward to do the uniq-ing using awk, but awk won't work in-place.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with using a temporary file, just that I'm curious as to why I can't write it to the same file.

Comment: Ah, as a general question about shell redirection? I suppose it's tied to the fact that redirecting into a file truncates it, and the output redirection has to start at the same time as the input redirection. That said, it could be a rule that the output redirection is done by creating an empty replacement for the file, rather than truncating it, which i think would allow this to work. Sadly, someone long ago decided that was not the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use a variable:

```
file='.zhistory' && var=$(sort -u "$file") && echo "$var" > "$file"
```

The reason you can't write to the same file is that the [redirection](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshmisc) occurs first and truncates the file before the utility ever sees it.

You can prevent duplicate lines in the first place. Use `setopt` with one or more of the following settings (from [`man zshoptions`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshoptions)):

> HIST_EXPIRE_DUPS_FIRST
>                 If the internal history needs to be trimmed to add  the  current
>                 command  line, setting this option will cause the oldest history
>                 event that has a duplicate to be lost  before  losing  a  unique
>                 event  from  the  list.   You should be sure to set the value of
>                 HISTSIZE to a larger number than SAVEHIST in order to  give  you
>                 some  room for the duplicated events, otherwise this option will
>                 behave just like HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS once the history fills  up
>                 with unique events.
>
> HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS
>                 When  searching  for  history entries in the line editor, do not
>                 display duplicates of a  line  previously  found,  even  if  the
>                 duplicates are not contiguous.
>
> HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS
>                 If a new command line being added to the history list duplicates
>                 an older one, the older command is removed from the  list  (even
>                 if it is not the previous event).
>
> HIST_IGNORE_DUPS (-h)
>                 Do  not  enter  command  lines into the history list if they are
>                 duplicates of the previous event.
>
> HIST_SAVE_NO_DUPS
>                 When writing out the history file, older commands that duplicate
>                 newer ones are omitted.

Answer (score 2):

The program **sponge** can be useful to write back in the same file you read.

(For the example's sake, you don't know about sed -i)

```
echo "say what again" > file
sed s/what/woot/ file > file
```

So bad, file is now empty, you lost your file.

```
echo "say what again" > file
sed s/what/woot/ file | sponge file
```

does what you want

(Be careful **not** to write `sponge > file` or the file will be empty again.)

Comment: `sponge` is in a package called `moreutils`. Check in the package manager of the OS

Answer (score 1):

The fact that i didn't have an answer to this question annoyed me sufficiently that i wrote one - call this inplace and put it executably on your path:

```
#! /bin/bash

BACKUP_EXT=
while getopts "b:" flag
do
    case "$flag" in
        b) BACKUP_EXT="$OPTARG" ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

CMD="$1"
shift

for filename in "$@"
do
    TMP_FILE="$(mktemp -t)"
    bash -c "$CMD" <"$filename" >"$TMP_FILE"
    if [[ -n "$BACKUP_EXT" ]]
    then
        mv "$filename" "$filename.$BACKUP_EXT"
    fi
    mv "$TMP_FILE" "$filename"
done
```

You may now say:

```
inplace 'sort | uniq -du' .zhistory
```

Incidentally, there's a way to do that uniqification without having to sort - but that's an answer for another question!

Comment: A bash script to modify zsh behaviour? Repent, heretic! :-)